# Mensagem sobre tag inválida(untagged)

Tags: bug, tradução, localização

Achei algumas perguntas com tags inválidas ao editar ela, apareceu a mensagem parcialmente em inglês como na imagem.

[image: image untagged]

Comment: Marcado como [meta-tag:localização] porque a [string não existe no Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english?q=this%20is%20a%20special%20tag).

Comment: Que estranho. Eu só tinha visto "untagged" em perguntas migradas aqui do meta ou do SOen. Mas havia duas que não se encaixavam nisso ([1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33412/uncaught-node-js-error), [2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37134/quebra-de-linha-no-visualg)). Parece um bug mesmo.

Comment: @bfavaretto ontem eu adicionei  umas tags numa pergunta de 'glassfish' desconfio que única tag q estava na pergunta era 'jdk' mudei para 'java' e 'sdk'